# Selinux on Fedora 25 is not letting me connect to a pptp vpn

Tags: fedora, openvpn, vpn, selinux

I'm not currently in UK and I need to login to my free UK based Spotify account on Fedora 25, the country I'm in isn't supported by Spotify.

I tried many free PPTP UK VPN services, they work on other distros but not on Fedora. I don't want to buy paid VPN because all I need is 1 min login authentication, after that I won't use a VPN.

On ask fedora they said you should use a cert, but PPTP does not provide a cert.

The only error message I can retrieve is this

```
SELinux is preventing systemd from create access on the unix_stream_socket Unknown.

*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************

If you believe that systemd should be allowed create access on the Unknown unix_stream_socket by default.
Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do
allow this access for now by executing:
# ausearch -c 'systemd' --raw | audit2allow -M my-systemd
# semodule -X 300 -i my-systemd.pp

Additional Information:
Source Context                system_u:system_r:init_t:s0
Target Context                system_u:system_r:unconfined_service_t:s0
Target Objects                Unknown [ unix_stream_socket ]
Source                        systemd
Source Path                   systemd
Port                          <Unknown>
Host                          localhost.localdomain
Source RPM Packages           
Target RPM Packages           
Policy RPM                    selinux-policy-3.13.1-224.fc25.noarch selinux-
                              policy-3.13.1-225.3.fc25.noarch
Selinux Enabled               True
Policy Type                   targeted
Enforcing Mode                Enforcing
Host Name                     localhost.localdomain
Platform                      Linux localhost.localdomain 4.8.6-300.fc25.x86_64
                              #1 SMP Tue Nov 1 12:36:38 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64
Alert Count                   3
First Seen                    2017-01-10 18:13:12 EET
Last Seen                     2017-01-10 18:13:12 EET
Local ID                      5c7e9912-af2e-480b-944c-09466a765d3f

Raw Audit Messages
type=AVC msg=audit(1484064792.751:301): avc:  denied  { create } for  pid=1 comm="systemd" scontext=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:unconfined_service_t:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0


Hash: systemd,init_t,unconfined_service_t,unix_stream_socket,create
```

Comment: *I forgot what the error message* ... I had the answer, but I forgot it.

Comment: I am using openVPN on Fedora for three years and I never saw SELinux blocking it "by default". The AVCs are visible in the SELinux Troubleshoot tool.

Comment: @Jakuje updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue solved, [this guy](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/100123/selinux-on-fedora-25-is-not-letting-me-connect-to-a-pptp-vpn/) gave me [this link](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/94500/connection-via-vpn-pptp-does-not-work-unless-firewall-is-disabled/?answer=94596#post-id-94596)

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT 0 -p gre -j ACCEPT
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv6 filter INPUT 0 -p gre -j ACCEPT
firewall-cmd --reload
modprobe nf_conntrack_pptp nf_conntrack_proto_gre
```

Comment: thanks, worked for me.